# bootstrap 3 input inside a div is jumping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, input

I have a problem with bootstrap css.

In the fiddle just type something to the input then input jumps up some pixels... WHY?

```
<div class="test"><input type="text" value="ABC"></div>

.test { height:86px; overflow:hidden; border:solid #000 3px; }
.test input { height:74px; margin:8px 0 0 6px; font-size:74px; }
```

---

So I want to use margin-top or somthing else to positioning lower the input inside the outter div

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKo7d.jpg)

```
<div class="test"><input type="text" value="ABC"></div>
.test { height:86px; overflow:hidden; border:solid #000 3px; }
.test input { height:74px; margin-top:20px; font-size:74px; }
```

[New fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p52nc59j/3/)

Comment: It's because the input is overflowing the parent. It has 74px height, plus 1px for each border (top and bottom), plus margins = 74+2+8+6 = 90 > 86.
I tried using `margin: 5px 0 0 5px` for the input and it stops jumping.

Comment: Yes I want to overflowing it

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear but it render better with this :

**Css** :

```
.test { height:86px; overflow:hidden; border:solid #000 3px; }
.test input { height:86px; margin:0; font-size:74px; padding-bottom: 10px;}
```

**Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/ja8mymtr/1/

Comment: I must to use margin-top to positioning lower the input

Answer (score 0):

That is a bit weird but you can fix it by using absolute position like this

```css
.test { 
  height:86px; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  border:solid #000 3px; 
  position: relative
}
.test input { 
  height:74px; 
  margin:8px 0 0 6px; 
  font-size:74px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <input type="text" value="ABC">
</div>
```

Comment: If I use top:20px there is the same mystic jumping

Comment: I have no idea, it seems that you have to use bottom instead

Answer (score 0):

> ... input jumps up some pixels... WHY?

After a lot of messing around I have finally zeroed in on the issue, phew.

You have set the `overflow` property of the container div to `hidden`. But, the inner content of that div, has more `height` than the parent (*counting the margin in, and the font size of the input*).

Due to which when a user types something in the input element, the browser tries to center the element by **`scrolling`** to it, its just that we aren't able to see it.

And hence we see the **"jump"**.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p52nc59j/4/)** *with the scroll bar **shown**, for further demonstration of what is happening.*

> *So I want to use margin-top to positioning lower the*
>   *input inside the outer div, while avoiding the jump*

You can reduce the `font-size` and `line-height` to something which can make the input element fit snugly in the container while retaining the margins. Something like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/p52nc59j/6/)**.

Comment: It's a perfect statement! Any solution to avoid jump to keep margin-top and overflow hidden?

Comment: If the fontsize can be reduced then try reducing the `font-size` to something that doesnt make the input overflow with the margin added.

Comment: I can't. I have an unique font which visible height is smaller than real height. So I try to oversize them and hide the overflow.

Comment: Try using `line-height` to your benefit.

Comment: I tried it, but not helps - it seems does not matter so no change the line height